# Casting System.__ComObject to known type reflection

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, reflection

I am trying to create an Excel file using reflection. The reason, the application will be running on many machines some of which may or not have excel installed. I decided to embed the "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll" and via reflection generated the excel spreadsheet.
The code I am trying to resemble is:

```
Dim app as new Excel.Application
Dim wb as Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1)
Dim ws as Excel.Worksheet = wb.Worksheets(1)
```

At the moment all is fine except when I retrieve a reference to the Worksheet instance which returns as a "System.__ComObject".

Is there a way I could cast the "System.__ComObject" to a "Worksheet type"?

I know that the underlying "System.__ComObject" is of type "Worksheet" as the exceptions thrown after searching for properties on the object give me errors indicating that it is in fact a "Worksheet" type. For instance:  "Type Worksheet doesn`t present the certain property,..."
Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Interesting read http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ArcGISDevHelp/DevelopmentEnvs/DotNet/SystemComObject.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the __ComObject in a runtime callable wrapper, RCW. You can have a look at this : [CreateWrapperOfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.createwrapperoftype.aspx)